# "Runtime: custom" access to project id, Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

We're trying to automaticaly load service accounts depending on the App Engine environment running (dev, staging, prod)

The thing is we are using a custom docker image based on

```
FROM node:15.14.0-alpine
```

Does anyone know how we would load the service account json automatically?

Comment: Tip: Do not include service account JSON key files in your App Engine deployments.

Answer (score 1):

With App Engine (and the other Google Cloud product) the service account is loaded automatically and accessible through the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata). With some product you can choose the service account that you want to use with your service, with other not (such as Cloud Build and App Engine).

With App Engine, the default (and unique) service account is `<project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`. If you want to have 3 different services, for 3 different environments with 3 different permissions, you have to create 3 different projects.

*Note: if you use custom App Engine runtime environment, have a close look to Cloud Run*

Comment: Great thanks for this; but how does this work with a custom image? Yes we have three different projects :-)

Comment: @OliverDixon - the answer depends on how your code/software is accessing credentials. Normally when deploying to Google Cloud compute services, the SDKs will fetch credentials from the Metadata server. Nothing special is required. Investigate how ADC (Application Default Credentials) work in Google Cloud.

Comment: From NodeJS via the environmental vars; but cause it's a custom docker image it doesn't have access to standard Metadata stuff. So still scratching my head here.

Comment: Why it haven't access to the metadata? The metadata are only a url to reach locally in your runtime environment

Comment: Ahh so the meta server is locked to an internal environement? So this could work with any docker image? (with app engine?)

Comment: Many of the Google Cloud NPM packages won't work this way though since 'service_account.json' is missing on the ENV var so it doesn't fix my issue :-/

Comment: Arf, if NPM packages are bad designed, it's hard to find a nice solution!